# Cycles takes an abnormally long time to render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I'm rendering an image in my animation using cycles to test out how long it will take to render a frame but it's been five minutes and blender hasn't even started on the first pixel. I know that this could just be that my computer is bad but I have a GTX 1070 and whenever I preview on cycles in the viewport it works just fine.

[image: The rendering viewport has stayed this way for five minutes.]

The rendering viewport has stayed this way for five minutes.
To add more detail, when I exit out of the rendering view to try again, blender doesn't respond and forces me to exit the program. Now that I realize it, that sentence sounds like I'm trying to make blender seem bad but I don't want to display that tone sorry lol.

One last thing is that I have a large texture file and a smoke simulation which could be the reason that it's taking so long to render(or not rendering at all) but then why would my viewport render work so well?

[image]
This is an image of my render in the viewport at 32 samples. It took Blender about 30 seconds to make this image. I have set my image render to 64 samples so it should not take more than a minute to render.

Here is the image of the toolbar to make things more clear.

[image]

Anyway here's the blender file. I appreciate the help
[image]

Comment: In the absence of any other information, five minutes is not necessarily long.  As for why viewport can work faster than render, consider differences in viewport/render settings (esp. subdivision, but consider also render and particle settings.)

Comment: @Nathan Thanks for the tip, I added some more information to make things more clear. There are no subdivision surface modifiers on any of the objects so that shouldn't be a problem either but I'm checking again right now.

Comment: Are those particles or smoke sim? Particles in that quantity typically take anywhere from minutes to hours to load. If it is a smoke sim, then volumetric rendering may slow down the Cycles render. If you are using 4-8K+ textures and have a somewhat slower CPU clock speed, then those will also take a couple minutes to load.

Comment: welp I seem to have gotten it working but I have no idea how. I'll post again later if I figure out what was causing the problem